# Segmented buttons in Windows desktop applications?

Tags: windows-os

Is there an equivalent to the OS X segmented Buttons on Windows 7 / Windows 8 Desktop (not Metro) and if so, what does it look like?

Example in OS X (*Settings, Listening Key, Commands*):

[image: Segmented Buttons in OS X]

Answer (score 1):

In windows applications we normally use tabs in this scenario.

Comment: Should have mentioned that it's not for a settings page but for filtering settings on top of a table. So tabs are not suited in this case.

Comment: Sounds more like a ribbon control like in office applications like Excel, though this also has tabs.

Comment: If you are using WPF there is nothing stopping you from just making the segmented button control.